# rename file which couldn't be imported using InputFilter

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3, zend-inputfilter

I'm not quite sure how to ask this properly.
I import several files in one shot. The filenames include the matching systems where the files belong to. That works so far quite fine.
But there will be files with no match, because the system is not found. I need to marker them, so the user can check.

My idea is to import this files also to the webserver but in a different directory. The directory could be shown to the user afterwards.

My `InputFilter` does the import to the right location which is for the matching files.

```
$inputFilter->add([
            'type'     => 'Zend\InputFilter\FileInput',
            'name'     => 'PAD_Document_Path',  // Element's name.
            'required' => true,    // Whether the field is required.
            'filters'  => [        // Filters.
                    [
                            'name' => \Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload::class,
                            'options' => [
                                    'use_upload_name'=>true,
                                    'use_upload_extension' => true,
                                    'randomize' => false,
                                    'overwrite' => true,
                                    'target' => './public/files/pads',
                            ],
                    ],
            ],
            'validators' => [      // Validators.
                    [
                            'name' => \Zend\Validator\File\Extension::class,
                            'options' => [
                                    'extension' => 'pdf',
                                    'message' => 'File extension not match',
                            ],
                    ],
                    [
                            'name' => \Zend\Validator\File\MimeType::class,
                            'options' => [
                                    'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',    //'text/xls', 'text/xlsx',
                                    'message' => 'File type not match',
                            ],
                    ],
                    [
                            'name' => \Zend\Validator\File\Size::class,
                            'options' => [
                                    'min' => '1kB',  // minimum of 1kB
                                    'max' => '8MB',
                                    'message' => 'File too large',
                            ],
                    ],
            ]
    ]);
```

So can I use the `InputFilter` also to import the files with no match? If that is not possible, which way would be the best?

And other idea is to not import the not matching files at all, but then I would need to rename them at the clients system. That is probably not possible, isn't it?

I hope I explained it properly so everybody can understand.

Comment: I'm thinking this would be incorrect use of the InputFilter, which is to validate that the File uploaded is correct, not what to do with it. In my opinion you would have to handle this in the Controller or a Service for file handling. You could then question whatever logic handles this to see if any meet the criteria of needing further action and if so, then do this, else continue with next step.

Comment: But the InputFilter is recommended to give the target of the filecopy in case of success. (Zend-Tutorial). Do you have an idea for me, what to do with the non matching files?

Comment: This is true, as a download (upload for client, download for server) needs a (tmp) destination. However, would it not be simpler to put all of them in a tmp location (`target` option) and then have some logic determine which match and which don't? Doing this in Filter and/or Validator options is using them for a purpose they're not designed for.

Comment: ok understood, but if we go a step back, before importing. It is then the point of validation, if want to rename at this point, how would you do this?

Comment: Well, there's [this](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-filter/file/#rename), but that sets the rules for **all** files. As such, I would create a single rule and then, after form validation, handle the contents received. Presumably in a Controller, where I would differentiate between files matching conditions (like you stated in the first paragraph of your question) and those that do not match. The first I would handle in the "happy flow", what I would've expected in the first place. The latter would remain in the tmp (upload) directory (1/2)

Comment: ...directory. If there are any in the tmp directory because of this upload (this specific one, ie owned by uploading user), then the user gets redirected to a page where he needs to choose what they are/where they should be placed. For example files A through F are uploaded. A & B are fine, they're matched with systems X & Y. Remainder cannot be matched. User gets redirected to page where he has to choose, per file, if the file is for X or for Y. Then move (rename if necessary, see prev comment link) the files as correction. (2/2)

Comment: that's a good idea, please post it as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to comments discussion below question, we came to a possible solution.

(please give it a shot, else add your own answer when you solve it)

---

> if we go a step back, before importing. It is then the point of validation, if want to rename at this point, how would you do this?

[The docs](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-filter/file/#rename) show you the option for how to rename files, also by setting a target location for them. However, this is then a rule for **all** files.

You should create a rule such as this, to uniformly validate the files. When you need files send to specific locations based on criteria, e.g. file names, then you should create this logic after the form validation. In a Controller class for example. In that Controller you handle the files matching the requirements in your "happy flow" and leave in the temporary those that aren't matched.

If any files are not matched, you redirect the user to a location where he has to decide what the files are destined for and/or what to do with them. If there aren't any files you proceed as normal for your application's happy flow.

Example flow:

1. Files A through F are uploaded.
2. A & B are fine, they're matched with, and moved for, systems X & Y.

Alternate flow for files (C through F) not matched after 2 above

1. Remainder cannot be matched.
2. User gets redirected to page where he has to choose, per file, if the file is for X or for Y.
3. Move the files as correction to selected options